# How to print a report in Java?

Tags: java, printing

I came from C#.
.NET offers a reporting tool (Crystal Report) to print reports.
I'm using a JTable populated by a source.

How do I print the records from the JTable without using jTable.print()?
How can I control the layouting?
Is the only way to print reports in Java is to use java.awt.print and javax.print?

Comment: You might want to look into Jasper reports.

Comment: take a look at [Jasper Reports](http://www.jaspersoft.com/)

Comment: could you display an exemple of your JTable class ?

Comment: Maybe I want to use the Report Service in SQL Server in my Java Application.

Answer (score 1):

BIRT allows you to handle data from POJO (Plain Old Java Object) datasource, consult BIRT developer channel on youtube, there is a tutorial about that.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamicreports is suitable for the purpose you had mentioned. It is build on top of Jasperreports and it is simpler to use than Jasper reports.

http://www.dynamicreports.org/

You can find the examples here: http://www.dynamicreports.org/examples/examples-overview